# ROS/gazebo consulting service

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I was wondering if anyone is aware of a ROS/gazebo consulting service currently in place. I had a look at the [consultants-network page](http://www.osrfoundation.org/consultants-network) and it looks like my initial best candidate for some gazebo support service (hiDof) is at rest as the webpage seems to indicate. Meanwhile I recently received a poll from ClearPath about a support service they are aiming at putting in place - not sure where they are at...

Anyone has an idea of who could best provide gazebo support?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193868/ros/gazebo-consulting-service/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think we want to see business activities on this forum that much, so I keep my answer brief; We have an experience for a consultancy work for `Gazebo`, `drcsim`. Please contact [us](http://opensource-robotics.tokyo.jp/?page_id=56&lang=en).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We started [PickNik](https://picknik.ai/) to provide ROS consulting, including Gazebo. But particularly we focus on robot manipulation / MoveIt :-)

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2020-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1